# Listen to enable/disable events on Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, events, sencha-touch

I'm in the need to listen to a enable/disable event on a container and I've noticed that there's no such event. I tried to listen to it in case it wasn't mentioned in the docs but it definitely doesn't exist.

I google'd around a little and found this..

```
Ext.define('My.Custom.Container',{
    extend:'Ext.Container',
    onEnable:function(){
        console.log("it's listening");
    }
});
```

It looked promising but it didn't work at all.

Is there any way to listen to these events? I don't want to get jQuery mixed in here as it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container` xtype from which many components inherit methods does have an event which fires on changing of it's `disabled` state.  This event is called `disabledchange` and fires every time the container is either enabled/disabled.

In the below code we can see this in action working on a `button` purely as it gives a visually better demo (since you can immediately see the state) but it inherits the exact same method and event from Container.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            padding: 10,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Button To be disabled/enabled',
                listeners: {
                    disabledchange: function(button, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        console.log('changing my disabled state to ' + value);
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'click to disable/enable above button',
                listeners: {
                    tap: function() {
                        var isButtonDisabled = Ext.Viewport.query('button')[0].getDisabled();
                        Ext.Viewport.query('button')[0].setDisabled(!isButtonDisabled);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g46

Comment: that's interesting, I can't see how I missed that in the docs. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found an answer to my question.

```
Ext.define('My.custom.Container',{
   extend:'Ext.Container',
   config:{
      ....config....
   },
   enable: function(){
       this.callParent(arguments);
       // do something else;
   },
   disable: function(){
      this.callParent(arguments);
      // do something else;
   }
});
```

I'm still curious if there's another way around this though. So answers are still welcome.